# Window dispatchevent on load not working for inline script

Tags: javascript

I have a simple inline hbs script that should broadcast a custom event on window load:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var evt = new Event('global:initialize-alert-banners');
        window.dispatchEvent(evt, function(e) {
            console.log('why doesnt this broadcast?', e)
        });
    };
</script>
```

Using Node debugger, I can see that the evt variable is successfully created, but when it comes time to dispatch the event on window, nothing fires. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method doesn't accept a callback. You need to add an event listener to window before you dispatch the event:

```js
window.addEventListener('global:initialize-alert-banners', () => console.log('global:initialize-alert-banners dispatched'))

window.onload = function() {
  var evt = new Event('global:initialize-alert-banners');
  window.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

Comment: Huh, interesting, I would've thought that the callback function inside `dispatchevent` would fire no?

Comment: The [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method doesn't accept a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach EventListener

```
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{

    //code

});
```